# iOS Telegram won't show the special keyboard markup button

Tags: python, ios, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that has been written with python-telegram-bot library. There is a `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` that has the attribute `one_time_keyboard` set to `True`. When the user selects a button, the markup will hide but is accessible through a special telegram-issued button. But in the telegram IOS version, the markup is inaccessible when a button is selected. It works perfectly on Android and Windows versions of Telegram.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it a bug in the IOS version of Telegram? Here's a short version of my code:
I'm using the `ConversationHandler` class because I have many states of conversation and will share the `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` block.

```
keyboard_services = [
    [KeyboardButton("service1"), KeyboardButton("service2")]
]
reply_markup_services = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard_services, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True
)

.....

async def services(update, context)
    await update.message.reply_text(
            text=text_services,
            reply_markup=reply_markup_services,
        )
```

Comment: how did you solve it? I use nodejs but have the same issue on iphone with this type of menu